# how to use database mail from SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, database-mail

I try to use gmail in database mail. I have no problem to send out email from it. But how I can configure my send mail task to send out email by using database mail. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The SSIS Send mail task connects directly to a SMTP server - it doesn't use database mail.  If you want to use database mail, you would invoke it through an 'Execute T-SQL Statement' task that calls a stored procedure that wraps the database mail facility, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this article [Sending email from SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1731/sending-email-from-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)